# Proper way to use react-hook-form Controller with Material UI Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to use a custom Material UI `Autocomplete` component and connect it to `react-hook-form`.

> TLDR: Need to use Material UI Autocomplete with react-hook-form Controller without `defaultValue`

My custom `Autocomplete` component takes an object with the structure `{_id:'', name: ''}` it displays the name and returns the `_id` when an option is selected. The `Autocomplete` works just fine.

```js
<Autocomplete
  options={options}
  getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
  onChange={(event, newValue, reason) => {
    handler(name, reason === 'clear' ? null : newValue._id);
  }}
  renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} {...inputProps} />}
/>
```

In order to make it work with `react-hook-form` I've set the `setValues` to be the handler for `onChange` in the `Autocomplete` and manually register the component in an `useEffect` as follows

```js
useEffect(() => {
  register({ name: "country1" });
},[]);
```

This works fine but I would like to not have the `useEffect` hook and just make use of the register somehow directly.

Next, I tried to use the `Controller` component from `react-hook-form` to properly register the field in the form and not to use the `useEffect` hook

```js
<Controller
  name="country2"
  as={
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
      onChange={(event, newValue, reason) =>
        reason === "clear" ? null : newValue._id
      }
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Country" />
      )}
    />
  }
  control={control}
/>
```

I've changed the `onChange` in the `Autocomplete` component to return the value directly but it doesn't seem to work.

Using `inputRef={register}` on the `<TextField/>` would not cut it for me because I want to save the `_id` and not the `name`

[HERE](http://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-feather-6nvf6) is a working sandbox with the two cases. The first with `useEffect` and `setValue` in the `Autocomplete` my works. The second my attempt in using `Controller` component

Any help is appreciated.

> LE

After the comment from Bill with the working sandbox of MUI Autocomplete, I Managed to get a functional result

```js
<Controller
  name="country"
  as={
    <Autocomplete
      options={options}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option._id === value._id}
      renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Country" />}
    />
  }
  onChange={([, { _id }]) => _id}
  control={control}
/>
```

The only problem is that I get an `MUI Error` in the console

*Material-UI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Autocomplete to be controlled.*

I've tried to set an `defaultValue` for it but it still behaves like that. Also, I would not want to set a default value from the options array due to the fact that these fields in the form are not required.

The updated sandbox [HERE](http://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-platform-i7fwc)

Any help is still very much appreciated

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-079xx have you seen this?

Comment: @Bill thank you for the link, I went through it's a working example but I still face some other issues now related to the state of the autocomplete component. I've updated the question with a LE. Thank you

Comment: if you follow what's in the codesandbox, it should resolve the problem, right?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-material-ui-5-lazy-loaded-values-not-validated-in-autocomplete-controller-forked-egcsf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, I fixed this. But it revealed what I believe to be an error in Autocomplete.

First... specifically to your issue, you can eliminate the `MUI Error` by adding a *defaultValue* to the `<Controller>`. But that was only the beginning of another round or problems.

The problem is that functions for `getOptionLabel`, `getOptionSelected`, and `onChange` are sometimes passed the value (i.e. the `_id` in this case) and sometimes passed the option structure - as you would expect.

Here's the code I finally came up with:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
export default function FormTwo({ options }) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, control } = useForm();

  const getOpObj = option => {
    if (!option._id) option = options.find(op => op._id === option);
    return option;
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        name="country"
        as={
          <Autocomplete
            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={option => getOpObj(option).name}
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
              return option._id === getOpObj(value)._id;
            }}
            renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Country" />}
          />
        }
        onChange={([, obj]) => getOpObj(obj)._id}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={options[0]}
      />
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Setting a default value is not an option for me because the fields are not mandatory therefore they must be empty. Also I forked my sandbox and updated with your code. The clear option breaks the app, check it https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-forest-tmb6s

Comment: Both problems fixed easily enough. Just need to allow for an empty/null option in getOpObj and getOptionSelected. You can then pass null as the defaultOption.

Comment: CodeSandbox won't let me sign-in for some reason. Didn't know you could save forked sandboxes without signing in. But this appears to have worked. Check out: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bogdan-w9eg8

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-material-ui-5-lazy-loaded-values-not-validated-in-autocomplete-controller-forked-egcsf

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer (probably) works for the bugged version of Autocomplete. I think the bug was fixed some time after that, so that the solution can be slightly simplified.

This is very useful reference/codesandbox when working with react-hook-form and material-ui: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-601-j2df5?

From the above link, I modified the Autocomplete example:

```js
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';


const ControlledAutocomplete = ({ options = [], renderInput, getOptionLabel, onChange: ignored, control, defaultValue, name, renderOption }) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      render={({ onChange, ...props }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
          renderOption={renderOption}
          renderInput={renderInput}
          onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data)}
          {...props}
        />
      )}
      onChange={([, data]) => data}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      name={name}
      control={control}
    />
  );
}
```

With the usage:

```js
<ControlledAutocomplete
    control={control}
    name="inputName"
    options={[{ name: 'test' }]}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => `Option: ${option.name}`}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="My label" margin="normal" />}
    defaultValue={null}
/>
```

`control` is from the return value of `useForm(}`

Note that I'm passing `null` as `defaultValue` as in my case this input is not required. If you'll leave `defaultValue` you might get some errors from material-ui library.

**UPDATE:**

Per Steve question in the comments, this is how I'm rendering the input, so that it checks for errors:

```js
renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="Field Label"
                    margin="normal"
                    error={errors[fieldName]}
                  />
                )}
```

Where `errors` is an object from `react-hook-form`'s `formMethods`:

```js
const { control, watch, errors, handleSubmit } = formMethods
```

Comment: I'm curious how your handling required autocomplete fields - for me with render it doesn't seem to trigger the errors

Comment: @Steve - I can see multiple reasons why the errors aren't showing up, depending on: validation library and validation schema, component structure, field naming (e.g. you need to use indexes in the field name if you're using array field). If you'll provide more details about your case, I might tailor the response. In my case, I'm using `yup` for validation, so the field has `.required()` in its schema. I'll also add a quick example how I'm rendering the input, so that error is shown. Let me know, if it's helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without the renderInput prop? like just adding the register to the Autocomplete like so: {...register("myFieldName")} ?

Answer (score 10):

```
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/core/Autocomplete";
import { red } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@material-ui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@material-ui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";


export default function App() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  // const classes = useStyles();

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: { item: null }
  });

  const onSubmit = (formInputs) => {
    console.log("formInputs", formInputs);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setItemList([
      { id: 1, name: "item1" },
      { id: 2, name: "item2" }
    ]);
    setValue("item", { id: 3, name: "item3" });
  }, [setValue]);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="item"
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
              <Autocomplete
                onChange={(event, item) => {
                  onChange(item);
                }}
                value={value}
                options={itemList}
                getOptionLabel={(item) => (item.name ? item.name : "")}
                getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
                  value === undefined || value === "" || option.id === value.id
                }
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    label="items"
                    margin="normal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    error={!!errors.item}
                    helperText={errors.item && "item required"}
                    required
                  />
                )}
              />
            )}
          />

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setValue("item", { id: 1, name: "item1" });
            }}
          >
            setValue
          </button>

          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            size="large"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            // className={classes.submit}
          >
            submit
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Container>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-material-ui-5-lazy-loaded-values-not-validated-in-autocomplete-controller-forked-egcsf?file=/src/App.js:0-3054

Comment: Works for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I do not know why the above answers did not work for me, here is the simplest code that worked for me, I used `render` function of `Controller` with `onChange` to change the value according to the selected one.

```js
<Controller
control={control}
name="type"
rules={{
  required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
}}
render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
  <Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    options={['field', 'select', 'multiple', 'date']}
    onChange={(event, values) => onChange(values)}
    value={value}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="type"
        variant="outlined"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    )}
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have made it work pretty well including multiple tags selector as follow bellow. It will work fine with mui5 and  react-hook-form 7

```
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

//setup your form and control

<Controller
    control={control}
    name="yourFiledSubmitName"
    rules={{
        required: 'required field',
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
            multiple
            options={yourDataArray}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
            onChange={(event, item) => {
                onChange(item);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params} label="Your label" placeholder="Your placeholder"
                />
            )}
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a TypeScript version:

```
import { Autocomplete, AutocompleteProps, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { useController } from 'react-hook-form';

export interface FormAutoCompleteProps<
    T,
    Multiple extends boolean | undefined,
    DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined,
    FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
> extends Omit<AutocompleteProps<T | string, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>, 'renderInput'> {
    renderInput?: AutocompleteProps<T | string, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>['renderInput'];
    label?: ReactNode;
    name: string;
}

export default function FormAutoComplete<
    T,
    Multiple extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    DisableClearable extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
    FreeSolo extends boolean | undefined = undefined,
>({ name, label, ...props }: FormAutoCompleteProps<T, Multiple, DisableClearable, FreeSolo>) {
    const {
        field,
        fieldState: { error },
    } = useController({ name });

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            {...field}
            onChange={(_, value) => field.onChange(value)}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} helperText={error?.message} error={!!error} label={label} />}
            {...props}
        />
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
<FormAutoComplete
    name="days"
    label="Label here"
    multiple
    options={["a", "b", "c"]}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the other answers, as of April 15 2022, I was able to figure out how to get this working and render the label in the `TextField` component:

```
const ControlledAutocomplete = ({
  options,
  name,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  error,
  rules,
  helperText,
}) => (
  <Controller
    name={name}
    control={control}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
    rules={rules}
    render={({ field }) => (
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) =>
          option?.label ??
          options.find(({ code }) => code === option)?.label ??
          ''
        }
        {...field}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            error={Boolean(error)}
            helperText={helperText}
          />
        )}
        onChange={(_event, data) => field.onChange(data?.code ?? '')}
      />
    )}
  />
);

ControlledAutocomplete.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.arrayOf({
    label: PropTypes.string,
    code: PropTypes.string,
  }),
  name: PropTypes.string,
  control: PropTypes.func,
  defaultValue: PropTypes.string,
  error: PropTypes.object,
  rules: PropTypes.object,
  helperText: PropTypes.string,
};
```

In my case, `options` is an array of `{code: 'US', label: 'United States'}` objects.  The biggest difference is the `getOptionLabel`, which I guess needs to account for if both when you have the list open (and `option` is an object) and when the option is rendered in the `TextField` (when option is a string) as well as when nothing is selected.

Comment: First of all you check for the existence of the label how many times in this answer? `getOptionLabel={(option) => options.find(({ code }) => code === option)?.label ?? ''}` wouldn't be enough?

Also in the option you get the option directly why look into the original array for it's label?

What am I missing?

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using controller, with the help of register, setValue of useForm and value, onChange of Autocomplete we can achieve the same result.

```
const [selectedCaste, setSelectedCaste] = useState([]);
const {register, errors, setValue} = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  register("caste");
}, [register]);

return (
                <Autocomplete
                  multiple
                  options={casteList}
                  disableCloseOnSelect
                  value={selectedCaste}
                  onChange={(_, values) => {
                    setSelectedCaste([...values]);
                    setValue("caste", [...values]);
                  }}
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
                  renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <Checkbox
                        icon={icon}
                        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                        checked={selected}
                      />
                      {option}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  )}
                  style={{ width: "100%" }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      id="caste"
                      error={!!errors.caste}
                      helperText={errors.caste?.message}
                      variant="outlined"
                      label="Select caste"
                      placeholder="Caste"
                    />
                  )}
                />
);
```

Comment: We can, but we change the complexity of the component...

Comment: This appears more straight forward, but the method mentioned above would allow it to be much more scalable and easier to reuse across the app. Since the Control component is defined in the dedicated `ControlledAutoComplete` file, we can import that into any form across the app and simply pass in the control and form specific options from that form's file. This is especially handy if an api call in the forms file is retrieving the options for the AutoComplete.