# MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.None of the options match with `0`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am using MUI [autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) component with [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/).
I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63853097/14912334).

*ControlledAutoComplete.jsx*

```
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const ControlledAutoComplete = ({
  options = [],
  label,
  renderInput,
  getOptionLabel,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  name,
  errors,
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
          defaultValue={defaultValue}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={label}
              error={errors[name]}
              helperText={errors[name] && errors[name].message}
              onChange={(e, data) => field.onChange(data)}
            />
          )}
          {...field}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
            value === undefined || value === "" || option.id === value.id
          }
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default ControlledAutoComplete;
```

*AddFees.jsx*

```
          <ControlledAutoComplete
            control={control}
            name="enrollmentId"
            options={[{ id: 1, firstName: "John"}, { id: 2, firstName: "Jen" }]}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.firstName}`}
            label="Select Students"
            errors={errors}
            defaultValue={""}
          />
```

I am getting below warning,

> MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid.
> None of the options match with `0`.
> You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality test.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing it wrong. I was listening for `onChange` on text field while it should be on `AutoComplete`

```
const ControlledAutoComplete = ({
  options = [],
  label,
  renderInput,
  getOptionLabel,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  name,
  errors,
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label={label}
              error={errors[name]}
              helperText={errors[name] && errors[name].message}
            />
          )}
          {...field}
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
            value === undefined || value === "" || option.id === value.id
          }
          onChange={(_, data) => field.onChange(data)}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Usage,

```
          <ControlledAutoComplete
            control={control}
            name="enrollmentId"
            options={students}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.firstName}`}
            label="Select Students"
            errors={errors}
            defaultValue=""
          />
```

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/69295842-error-validation-with-material-ui-autcomplete-react-hook-form-lo09u?file=/src/MuiAutoComplete.js:928-1009)